# how a single ip mapped to multiple domain names?

Tags: nginx, networking, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt

I am facing an issue while working on a project. For example i had a ubuntu running with nginx configuration. I had configure wildcard with nginx like:-

main domain : xyz.com

wildcard : a.xyz.com, b.xyz.com working.

The above config is working with https with the help of let encrypt.
Here is my problem, that i am facing right now.

I want that if i give someone a.xyz.com, and then that someone want that a.xyz.com will listen that www.someone.com. Is that possible or not this is the question i am lokking into and if yes then please suggest how??

And if you think question header is nothing to do with my question then let me clear that the same issue i am facing shopify guys are doing some how.

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Vote down is ok but plz let me know why. Is my question is not a question or something else. And thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can below configuration

```
    server {
        listen        80;
        listen        443 ssl;
        server_name   a.xyz.com; 
        ssl_certificate /path/to/cert/YourCert.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://www.someone.com;
        }

    }

    server {
        listen        80;
        listen        443 ssl;
        server_name   b.xyz.com; 
        ssl_certificate /path/to/cert/YourCert.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://www.someone2.com;
        }

    }
```

Comment: does i had to config for everyone. is there any way to automate this? and thanks @vijay

Comment: @ManishYadav : You can automate this using the dev ops tools and scripts

Comment: ok that is ok but i am new to this stuff can you suggest some tools for that.

Comment: and the above config is not working for me @vijay singh

Comment: @ManishYadav Please share you full nginx configuration